# background-color css property not working in table

Tags: html, css, web

Here is html and CSS code:

```css
    table,th,td{
      border:1px solid blue;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td{
      text-align:center;
    }
    td{padding:10px;
      color:#cc7722;
    }
    table{
      border-spacing:5px;
      background-color:yellowgreen;
      font-weight:bold;
      width:100%
    }
    #hello{
      color:red;
    }
    .hi{
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
     <table>
          <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
          <tr>
            <div class="hi">
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>
              Department
            </th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Vaibhav</td>
            <td>CSE</td>
            <td>10000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQw8N.png)

**Here background color blue for class hi not shown** 
so what can be the reason 
and what is the possible solution for this

Comment: div is not allowed as a child of tr element. You only can put div into th or tr element.

Comment: Probably because the HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `div` as anything other than a cell value, you'll get misbehaving browsers.

Wrap your header row definition around the `thead` tag and style that instead. Don't forget to then wrap the body around `tbody`.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #cc7722;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%
}

#hello {
  color: red;
}

.hi {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
  <thead class="hi">
    <tr>

      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>
        Department
      </th>
      <th>Salary</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Vaibhav</td>
      <td>CSE</td>
      <td>10000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't use a div within a table for styling.  just apply the class to the tr itself

html

```
 <table>
   <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
   <tr class="hi">
     <th>Employee Name</th>
     <th>Department</th>
     <th>Salary</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Vaibhav</td>
     <td>CSE</td>
     <td>10000</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table shouldn't have a div inside, instead you have to do like this:

```
<tr class="hi">
```

Answer (score 1):

add `div` inside `th,td` it'll work not outside

```css
    table,th,td{
      border:1px solid blue;
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    td{
      text-align:center;
    }
    td{padding:10px;
      color:#cc7722;
    }
    table{
      border-spacing:5px;
      background-color:yellowgreen;
      font-weight:bold;
      width:100%
    }
    #hello{
      color:red;
    }
    .hi{
      background-color:blue;
    }
```

```html
     <table>
          <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
          <tr>
            
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>
              Department
            </th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div class="hi">Vaibhav</div></td>
            <td>CSE</td>
            <td>10000</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does moving the class to the th accomplish what you are wanting?

```css
table,th,td{
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  text-align:center;
}
td{padding:10px;
  color:#cc7722;
}
table{
  border-spacing:5px;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%
}
#hello{
  color:red;
}
.hi{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
      <tr class="hi">  
        <th >Employee Name</th>
        <th>
          Department
        </th>
        <th>Salary</th>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vaibhav</td>
        <td>CSE</td>
        <td>10000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: No reason for the person who downvoted you, have done so. Your answer is correct. I'm upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is changing the `<tr>` background, which you can easily accomplish by removing your `<div>` and giving the class to your `<tr>` tag. As the following:

```
<table>
      <caption id="hello">Employee Data</caption>
      <tr class="hi">
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vaibhav</td>
        <td>CSE</td>
        <td>10000</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

And your CSS is just the same.

```
table,th,td{
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
  text-align:center;
}
td{padding:10px;
  color:#cc7722;
}
table{
  border-spacing:5px;
  background-color:yellowgreen;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%
}
#hello{
  color:red;
}
.hi{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible to change html then You can use combination of thead, tbody to set different colors to table head and body.

Example

```
<style>
thead {color:green;}
tbody {background:blue;}
tfoot {color:red;}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>


   <table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Month</th>
     <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
     <td>January</td>
     <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

All `tr` in `tbody` will have background blue.

Otherwise you have to use styling for `tr`, `th` separately